# Jenkins - TestNG issue

Tags: jenkins

I have a batch file with the following information:

```
java org.testng.TestNG test.xml
```

Where test.xml is the testng suite xml. Now when I run the batch file (Runme.bat), the test scripts are triggered and working fine. All I wanted to do was to fire this batch file from jenkins. When I add it as a Build task to a project in jenkins like:

> cmd /k "C:\Runme.bat"

Running the build does not trigger the testNG suite instead gives the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG     at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)   at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     at
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) Could not find the
main class: org.testng.TestNG.  Program will exit. Exception in thread "main"  
C:\Documents and Settings\GopalakA\Desktop\AutomationAnand\ABC_JSAF> C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Test\workspace>exit 0
```

Even though the classpath is set correctly as I can trigger the suite by manually running the bat file.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Jenkins System info (`http://[jenkins_server]/systemInfo`) and check if indeed `CLASSPATH` variable is set correctly.

Comment: I checked the systemInfo, it is not updated to the current Classpath. How do I modify it?

Comment: Make sure 1) You run Jenkins on the same machine on which you are checking your Classpath; 2) The user under which Jenkins runs has the environment variable set correctly. You can also do it via Jenkins configuration (`http://[jenkins_server]/configure` -> Global Properties -> check Environment Variables -> set Classpath variable).

Comment: Thank you for your help scot. Now it says: [TestNG] [ERROR] 
Cannot find class in classpath:<test class file name>

Comment: I think this is a new problem and you should open another question with the full log. Tag it [jenkins] and [testng].

Comment: @andyrocks369 i am facing the same error as cannot find class in class path . if at all you solved that error please update me

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to accomplished this task:-

Step 1:-

1. Go to localhost:8080/configure (Jenkins configure section)
2. Now go to JDK section and uncheck Install automatically (If you don't uncheck that then it will download latest java every time whenever it is available, and can cause  for build failed)
3. put JAVA_HOME in name section and jdk home path in JAVA_HOME section

[image]

4. Apply and save

Step 2:-

1. Go to Jenkins and add new Item, also select "Free Style Project" and click on Ok.
2. Click on "Advanced in "Advanced Project Options"
3. Now check option: - "Use custom workspace" and specify your project absolute path in Directory section

[image]

4. Apply
5. Now to go "Build" and select "Execute windows batch command"
6. Here in command column give the file name of your batch file 
   [image]
7. Apply and save

**Now go to the Jenkins and select your Jenkins project and click on Build :)**

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to achieve the goal of running TestNG tests in Jenkins, you should also consider running the test through maven. If you're project can run the test through 'mvn test' command then you can use Build with goal set as 'test'.

```
Invoke Maven 3
  Goals and options = test
```

You can also have nice benefit of test report integrated through sure-fire plugin if you set

```
test report XMLs = target/surefire-reports/*.xml
```